# array - out of memory in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a big array of associative arrays. Each associative array consists of around 15 keys of different types (string, integer, float) - Smaller example below:

```
$array = [
    [
      "key1" => "string",
      "key2" => 10,
      "key3" => 4.05
    ],       
    [
      "key1" => "string2",
      "key2" => 20,
      "key3" => 1.05
    ],       
   ...
];
```

Now I want to iterate over this array and add some keys like

```
$map = array_map(function (array $item) {            
       $item['key4'] = 1;
       $item['key5'] = 1;
       $item['key6'] = 1;
       return $item;
   }, $array);
```

**Problem:** For an array which contains quite a big number of associative arrays, adding new keys makes that there is memory limit reached and the script is terminated. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Protip: start using objects with classes, and back those with a database if you really have so much data to work with that you run out of memory. That's how storage works: cpu cache, if you run out of that, RAM, if you run out of that, time to use the filesystem.

Comment: If you have enough memory you can always increase the memory-limit 
 - http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for reply. You mean that I should use array of objects, is that right ?

Comment: @daker Increasing memory limit is not a solution in my case - and mostly in general. I can have an array containing once 200K arrays and then 800 K - I have to solve it on the code level.

Comment: To save some space, if your keys are often repeating, dont use full string keys - instead of key1, key2 etc, use just 0, 1 ... it will save some space

Comment: @MartinPerry Thanks for the tip. I take it into account. I think in my example it will be difficult to eliminate the names but still.. I think it is a good suggestion.

Comment: @Joe yes, start by representing your data with objects, rather than associative arrays, and then you can load/save batches of objects using quite a few disk-based solutions. A simple object store running on your data, for instance, would make working with millions of objects quite manageable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could paginate your data, chunk your array to work with smaller pieces, or even increase memory_limit, but let's assume that you have a big array and can't do otherwise.

So let’s play with a 1 000 000 long array and try different solutions. I'll put the memory consumption & compute time measurements from my laptop

## Current solution (857MB / 640ms)

```
for ($i=0; $i< 1000000; $i++){
    $array[$i] = [
        "key" => 'value',
        "key2" => $i,
        "key3" => $i / 3
    ];
}

$map = array_map(function (array $item) {
    $item['key4'] = 1;
    $item['key5'] = 1;
    $item['key6'] = 1;
    return $item;
}, $array);
```

With this piece of code the memory consumption on my laptop is **857MB and the compute time 640ms**.

In your example you are creating a whole new `$map` variable from your `$array`. This means you are making a fresh copy of the array in memory.

## Working with [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) (480MB / 220ms)

```
$array = [];
for ($i=0; $i< 1000000; $i++){
    $array[$i] = [
        "key" => 'value',
        "key2" => $i,
        "key3" => $i / 3
    ];
}

foreach ($array as &$item) {
    $item['key4'] = 1;
    $item['key5'] = 1;
    $item['key6'] = 1;
}
```

With the usage of `&$item` we asking PHP to give us access to the variable by reference, meaning that we are modifying the data directly in-memory without creating a new copy of it.

This is why it this script consumes a lot less memory & compute time.

## Working with classes (223MB / 95ms)

Under the hood, PHP uses C data structures to manage data in memory. Classes are predictable and much easier for PHP to optimize than an array. It is well explained [here](https://gist.github.com/nikic/5015323)

```
class TestClass {
    public $key1,   $key2, $key3,   $key4, $key5, $key6;
}

$array = [];
for ($i=0; $i< 1000000; $i++){
    $array[$i] = new TestClass();
    $array[$i]->key1 = 'value';
    $array[$i]->key2 = $i;
    $array[$i]->key3 = $i / 3;
}

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $item->key4 = 1;
    $item->key5 = 1;
    $item->key6 = 1;
}
```

You can see that the memory consumption & the time to iterate are much lower. This is because PHP don't need to modify the structure of the data in memory : every field of the object is ready to receive data.

Be careful, though, if you add a field that wasn't declared in the class (eg. `$item->newKey = 1` : newKey is declared dynamically) : memory optimisation won't be possible anymore and you'll jump to 620mb memory usage & 280ms compute)

---

If you want to go further and are not afraid of headaches, take a look to the [Standard PHP Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) (SPL) : you will find a lot of optimized data structures solutions (Fixed Arrays, Iterators & so on...)

PS : benchmark made with Xdebug disabled

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to save some memory if you utilize references. This will remove many copy on write actions that occur the background. In a small test case. I was able to reduce the memory by 30%-40% (depending on the PHP version). If you use PHP5, you can also profit from an upgrade to PHP7. Obviously I can't predict if either or both save enough memory.
Test Case (just remove the `/*` before map or walk):

```
$cnt=10000;
for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++) {
  $array[]['key1'] = 1;
  $array[]['key2'] = 2;
  $array[]['key3'] = 3;
}
/*array_walk($array, function (&$item,$key) {            
   $item['key4'] = 1;
   $item['key5'] = 1;
   $item['key6'] = 1;
}); //memory used PHP7/PHP5: 13 437 720 - 25 924 944 */
/*$map = array_map(function (array $item) {            
   $item['key4'] = 1;
   $item['key5'] = 1;
   $item['key6'] = 1;
   return $item;
}, $array); //memory used PHP7/PHP5: 25 050 360 - 40 850 480*/
```